# Better regular expression - PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have formed this regexp to get the digits just before the pattern '?haid'

```
Select regexp_substr(regexp_substr('https:-2027-11217432?haid=4052118&uperty1','-[[:digit:]]+\\?haid'),'[[:digit:]]+')

output : 11217432
```

Just wanted to check if there's a better way of writing it without using 2 regular expression or any other functions.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is using  [regexp_replace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html)

remove everything, except what wee need to keep:

```
select regexp_replace('https:-2027-11217432?haid=4052118&uperty1', '.*[^\d](\d+)\?haid.*', '\1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use *SUBSTRING*

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING('https:-2027-11217432?haid=4052118&uperty1' FROM '.*-(\d+)\?haid.*')
```

Or REGEXP_REPLACE

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('https:-2027-11217432?haid=4052118&uperty1', '.*-(\d+)\?haid.*', '\1')
```